# Unable to get value in success in ajax in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, callback, jquery-callback

I am not getting value in success in Ajax in FIREFOX specifically, it is working fine in IE and Chrome.
Servlet Code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");String json = "";
    if(br!=null)
    {
        json=br.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println("JSON"+json);
    try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
        Iterator iterKey = jObj.keys(); 

    // create the iterator for the json object.
    while(iterKey.hasNext()) {
        String jsonKey = (String)iterKey.next(); //retrieve every key ex: name, age
        String jsonValue = jObj.getString(jsonKey); //use key to retrieve value from 

        //This is a json object and will display the key value pair.

        System.out.println(jsonKey  + " --> " + jsonValue  );
        myData.add(jsonValue);
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`out.print("Hi");`

The JSP code is below, it is working fine in IE and Google Chrome browser. I have also updatef Firefox to latest.

```
function formSubmit(){
                var article = new Object();
                article.releasename=$('#dropDownRelease').val();
                article.morname=$('#dropDownMor').val();
                article.pathname=$('#dropDownPath').val();
                article.buildname=$('#dropDownBuild').val();
                article.filename=$('#filePath').val();
                $.ajax({
                url: 'UploadReportServlet',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data:JSON.stringify(article),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                     alert(data);
               },
               error:function(data,status,er) {
                   alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                  }
            });
        };
```

Comment: What error does the firefox console show?

Comment: @C0dekid how can i see that? Please guide.

Comment: 1) Right click on that page. 2) Select 'Inspect element' 3) Switch to the 'Console' tab. 4) Refresh the page and reproduce the error by doing the steps that should have working.

Comment: IMHO (haven't tested): you set the response type to `"application/json;charset=UTF-8"`, but the response content is `Hi!`, which is not a valid JSON. And Firefox breaks on that error, whereas IE and Chrome ignore it.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Now i am getting pop-up but just for millisecond.

Comment: @C0dekid i am getting NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED error.